# How to implement bearer token authentication in MVC4/ WebAi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Can somebody give me a sample code or a guidance on  how to implement **HostAuthenticationFilter** in MVC4/WebApi 2 project where I have implemented Cookie based authentication in MVC4 project and then I added an Area called Api where I have exposed EDM using WebApi2 and OData V3 but I need to implement OAuth 2 token i.e. bearer based authentication in order to access api controller. In addition to this, I need login controller in my api as clients are Native Mobile Apps (iOS and Android users). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading all the related articles online throughout the day and finally found the similar case [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/487) and then I decided to follow [this sample](https://github.com/B3nCr/IdentityServer-Sample).

Finally, Its better to separate the API and Frontend MVC4 in different projects in order to avoid the complexity of Cookies and Token based security and other issues.